# AIogram bot не отправляет клавиавтуру KeyboardButton в группу

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot, aiogram

Бот не отправляет клавиатуру в общую группу(которая крепится внизу), но может отправить ее в лс. Но он может отправить инлайн клавиатуру(которая крепится к сообщению). Данная возможность вообще предоставляется телеграмом? Права есть, другие сообщения пишет, которые без KeyboardButton

Answer (score 0):

Если ты про такую штуку, то делаеться она оч просто

```
  @dp.message(Command(commands="start", prefix="/"))
async def start(message: Message):
        await message.answer("gg", reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard=[
            [KeyboardButton(text="ggww")]
        ]))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Странно, у меня такой-же подход, просто клавиатуры храню в отдельном файле

Comment: Короче, я понял. У меня была кнопка с веб ап, но судя по ошибке она разрешает только в приватных чатах: web App buttons can be used in private chats only

Comment: рад, что получилось решить проблемму